# ActiveRecord - speed up this rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there anything I can do to speed up this migration.  It is needed to populate historical data as some new columns have been added.

It needs to populate over 200,000 rows and it takes about an hour.  I didnt use native sql as our test, local dev and deployed sql databases are all different and would require 3 different sql scripts, so I thought active record would be best to do it.

The migration performs a simple calculation, multiplying two values to create the new value which is stored.

```
class PopulateMissingItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    begin
      Item.where('items.item_status_id' => [Item::HISTORICAL]).find_each(start: 0, batch_size: 2000) do |item|
        item.ignore_update_user = true # don't update the user id

        item.ine_items.each do |line_item|
          line_item.apply_exchange_rate (item.us_exchange_rate)
        end
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Think over and remove the nested loops. The time complexity will follow the pattern O(N^2) which should be avoided

Comment: Just to make sure - `apply_excahnge_rate` saves the record?

Comment: How about `Break it down, so multiple threads can run it`? Eg thread 1 runs first 1000 entries, thread 2 runs next 1000 entries,...

Comment: First off all, using a specific database to each environment is not a good idea. Each database could have a different behaviour on some operations. If it is a simple calculation, a sql would resolve that.

Comment: Thanks I know its not ideal to have different databases, but its out of my hands.  Yes, apply_exchange_rate saves the record

Comment: Not entirely the point of the question but migrations are more or less one-off right? Why worry so much if it "only" runs one hour? If it's for the sake of avoiding the mistake / learning something from this, ignore what I said.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of ActiveRecord's [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) method which enables you to update all records of a given relation within a single SQL statement.

Assuming a new `total` integer column was added to an existing `LineItem` model with two existing `some_int` and `other_int` columns, the migration could be written as follows:

```
class PopulateMissingItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    begin
      Item.where(item_status_id: [Item::HISTORICAL]).find_each(start: 0, batch_size: 2000) do |item|
        item.line_items.update_all('total = some_int + other_int')
      end
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
    end
end
```

This will execute one update statement for each Item. It's also possible to update all Line item for all items with a single statement, but that depends on other factors.

An important note is that update_all (from docs):

> It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.